# How can i go to next iteration when i click a buttom in a while loop?

Tags: java, swing, while-loop

I am making a quiz. I store my question in an array. So I use a while loop to display the question one by one. When I click the button, the counter +1 and go to next iteration which is next question. However it seems like that the it does not work out.

```
final int[] k = {0};
while (k[0] <2){
    ql.setText(qa[k[0]][0]);
    ql.setVisible(true);

    for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++) {
        ch[l].setVisible(true);
        ch[l].setText(String.valueOf((int) (50 * Math.random())));
    }
    rc = (int) (4 * Math.random());
    ch[rc].setText(qa[k[0]][1]);

    nx.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            k[0]++;
        }
    });
}
```

What is the problem here?
Thanks!!

Comment: Why is `k` an `int[]` and not an `int`? If you want to move to the next iteration of the loop, you can use `continue`.

Comment: yes, since it is defined as `int[] k = {0};` which is an array with only one element. I think, there's a fundamental misunderstanding too how the actionlistener might interact with the loop. The code, once it compiles, theoretically will add **many** action listeners, it will loop, until the action got fired twice and in each iteration add another listener. Don't know, though, how it works out in practice. Probably as you said: it does not work out. Maybe what you want is to create the listener outside the loop.

Comment: @AnilM, you cannot modify an effectively final variable inside a closure in java. So using an array of single value is usually how people get around this

Comment: @ScaryWombat, if you look closely, it is actually `qa[k[0]][1]` which means this line is accessing a multi dimensional array called `qa`

Comment: @smac89 You are so correct.

Comment: @smac89 That is quite clever! Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to invert your loop to work in an event-driven style. So what I'm thinking is, you should have the button click drive the "loop" in that it will only activate the questions provided your counter has not run down, otherwise it will just ignore any more presses.

Something like:

```
private void showQuestion(int question) {
    ql.setText(qa[question][0]);
    ql.setVisible(true);

    for (int l = 0; l < 4; l++) {
        ch[l].setVisible(true);
        ch[l].setText(String.valueOf((int) (50 * Math.random())));
    }
    int rc = (int) (4 * Math.random());
    ch[rc].setText(qa[question][1]);
}

...
// In some method...
nx.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    int nextQuestion = 1;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (k < 1) {
            showQuestion(nextQuestion++);
        }
    }
});
showQuestion(0); // Shows the first question
```

Comment: However I have to press the button first, then it goes to the first question.

Comment: I have ten questions in total.

Comment: So you basically display the first question, then when button clicked every time display following question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your code but the most fundamental (focusing on your question) is that you are misunderstanding the difference between a loop in your code (e.g. `for`) and the GUI event loop. Loops in your code execute and then finish. GUI event loops wait until the user performs some action and then respond to it. It is not desirable to have a code loop waiting for some user action before continuing: that's just not how GUIs work.

I suggest you read the section in the swing tutorial on writing event listeners: [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html). It explains how to get your code correctly responding to events triggered by users.